# gwt, path to external source folder

Tags: java, gwt, path, config

I want include to gwt client side classes from another package, and don't want to write addition .gwt.xml.
I wrote complex relative path like this:

```
<source path="../../../../../../../../logic/src/p1/p2/p3/p4/p5/p6"/>
```

It's seems right path, but gwt can't import classes and throw warning:

> GWT Compiler: Non-canonical source package:
>   .../../../../../../../../logic/src/p1/p2/p3/p4/p5/p6/

Should i use additional gwt-module, or my solution right, but with bug?

I don't want use gwt-module, because it's bad to write client configs on logic side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `<source path="">` is to specify the package and the subpackages under the specified package that contains code translatable into javascript. So, you cannot specify a folder which is not in your current gwt module. In other words, the source path should be under the directory which contains your gwt.xml file. This being the case, the solution to your problem is either you include all the source as one gwt module or create multiple gwt modules.

Comment: how to create multiple gwt modules?

Answer (score 0):

source path="path" are basically used to specify where your javascript translated code would be. So it should be under the same directory as your gwt.xml is